# "display" CSS property is not rendered by SASS

Tags: sass

I'm using Sass 3.1.20

test.sass:

```
#hello
  width: 100px
  display:none 
  background: red
```

%> sass test.sass

```
#hello {
  width: 100px;
  background: red; }
```

Why is the display property being skipped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like SASS is picky about whitespace. You're missing a space here:

```
#hello
  width: 100px
  display: none
          ^ right here

  background: red
```

Comment: It's pretty easily missable, as normally css doesn't really care about that